# How to do click on the drawn shape

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

how to click on a drawn figure so that after clicking it disappears, so far it has turned out to click on the entire playing area.

```
    if (FlxG.mouse.pressed) 
    {
        remove(circle); 
    }
```

Comment: What is `FlxG`? Please review the minimum reproducible example doc: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking if the mouse is being pressed, you should first check if the mouse is overlapping the sprite and only get the click when that's true.

An example https://gamefromscratch.com/haxeflixel-tutorial-mouse-input/